# Webpack: Is it possible hot module rebuild (not reload)?

Tags: webpack

For example, I have two bundle file :`A.js` and `B.js`. But only `B.js` depend on module `C`.

When the first build happened, both `A.js` and `B.js` have to build. But when the `C` module get updated, the next I run build command, the webpack should only build `B.js`, which do the build optimiztion automatic for me. So I could save lots of build time.

Webpack can achieve this ? If it can, how should config my webpack?

Comment: Note that `webpack --watch` does something similar: build the whole project on command launch, but only update necessary modules on file saves thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a built-in Webpack feature, but [`only-if-changed-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/only-if-changed-webpack-plugin) does just that. Minimal use case:

```js
const path = require('path');
const OnlyIfChangedPlugin = require('only-if-changed-webpack-plugin');

const opts = {
  rootDir: process.cwd(),
  devBuild: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
};

module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(opts.rootDir, 'build'),
    pathinfo: opts.devBuild,
  },
  plugins: [
    new OnlyIfChangedPlugin({
      cacheDirectory: path.join(opts.rootDir, 'tmp/cache'),
      cacheIdentifier: opts, // all variable opts/environment should be used in cache key
    })
  ],
};
```